# My if statement "between" is giving me wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am new here. I have a problem with my if/else if statement.

I got this:

```
  if (unalumno.notas >= "90" && unalumno.notas <= "100") {
      unalumno.notas = "A";
  } else if (unalumno.notas >= "80" && unalumno.notas <= "89") {
      unalumno.notas = "B";
  } else if (unalumno.notas >= "70" && unalumno.notas <= "79") {
      unalumno.notas = "C";
  } else if (unalumno.notas >= "60" && unalumno.notas <= "69") {
      unalumno.notas = "D";
  } else if (unalumno.notas <= "59") {
      unalumno.notas = "F";
  }
```

All the **else if** statement is giving to me the right result in letters, but the first **if** continue giving the result in numbers. Hope can understand me. Sorry for english lol

Have a good day

Comment: You're comparing strings, which means `"90" > "100"` is TRUE, because `9` comes after `1` in the charset.

Comment: You should convert to an integer before comparing `unalumno.notas = parseInt(unalumno.notas, 10)`, and remove the quotes around all of the values you are comparing `unalumno.notas` to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment, parse the integer out and change all of your comparisons to numbers instead of strings:

```
var unalumnoNotas = parseInt(unalumno.notas, 10);
if (unalumnoNotas >= 90 && unalumnoNotas <= 100) {
 notas = "A";
} else if (unalumnoNotas >= 80 && unalumnoNotas <= 89) {
 notas = "B";
} else if (unalumnoNotas >= 70 && unalumnoNotas <= 79) {
 notas = "C";
} else if (unalumnoNotas >= 60 && unalumnoNotas <= 69) {
 notas = "D";
} else if (unalumnoNotas <= 59) {
 notas = "F";
}
```

Also, if you throw an error or return early if the value is greater than 100, you can remove all of the extra `&& <= 89`

```
if (unalumnoNotas > 100) {
    throw new Error('Number too high');
}

if (unalumnoNotas >= 90) {
 notas = "A";
} else if (unalumnoNotas >= 80) {
 notas = "B";
} else if (unalumnoNotas >= 70) {
 notas = "C";
} else if (unalumnoNotas >= 60) {
 notas = "D";
} else if (unalumnoNotas <= 59) {
 notas = "F";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use integers for comparison, or just parseInt("your string").

Comment: ah you're right, i've read it diagonally, gonna edit that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings instead of the integers that you should be comparing. Instead of the numerical comparison you think you're doing, its actually comparing the position of the characters in the string on their ASCII position.

You should parse the value into an `int` type then compare to numbers instead of strings.